# JPA : Join and group by sum. MySQL query

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, join

I've got two tables : `sales` and `products`

```
[Products]
+-------+-------------------+
| id    | name              |
+-------+-------------------+
| 1     | product number 1  |
| 2     | product number 2  |
| 3     | product number 3  |
+-------+-------------------+

[Sales]
+-------+------------+------+
| id    | product_id | qty  |
+-------+------------+------+
| 1     | 2          | 100  |
| 2     | 2          | 35   |
| 3     | 1          | 1    |
+-------+-------------------+
```

I'd like to display something like this with JavaEE and JPA :

```
Most selled products :
+------------------+------------+
| Product name     | Quantity   |
+------------------+------------+
| product number 2 | 135        |
| product number 1 | 1          |
+------------------+------------+
```

I'm facing two problems :

- I only know how to retrieve objects, so I could display the product's name, but not the quantity selled, as it's a computed value.
- I don't know how to query my database to retrieve the right informations

This is what I've tried :

```
public List<Product> getMostSelledProducts() {
    Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Sale s RIGHT JOIN Product p GROUP BY s.productId ORDER BY COUNT(s.productId)");
    return q.getResultList();
}
```

How should I do such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this will work, didn't test it, but might set you on the right path if it doesn't work.

```
SELECT p.name, SUM(s.qty) as Quantity FROM Sales s 
INNER JOIN Product p ON s.product_id = p.id 
GROUP BY s.product_id 
ORDER BY Quantity DESC
```

Comment: Thanks :) But then, what should be the type of response? I can't return a product, as I would loose the quantity information...

Comment: Could you return just a List instead of List<Product>?